# Sum of positive integers while choosing signs

Tags: number-theory

The question is :
Let n be greater than or equal to $2$, and let $a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n$ be positive integers whose sum is even, and such that $a_i \le i$. Prove that it is possible to choose signs for each number as such:
$\pm a_1 \pm a_2 \pm \cdots \pm a_n$ In such a way such that the sum is zero.

So I'm really stuck on this. I know that the sum has to be even due to the fact that you can split up the positives and the negatives. But I'm really stuck after that. Any help or solutions?

Comment: For $n=2$, $a_1 = 4$, $a_2=2$, no way of choosing signs makes the sum $0$.

Comment: Doesn't make sense. Say $n=2$, $a_1=1$, $a_2=3$. Must be something missing in the statement.

Comment: Ah I meant there are n integers sorry. a_1 with a subscript is what I meant.

Comment: @Sultan Well the above comments show that your question does not hold for 2 integers, so it doesn't hold when $n=2$. Is there a minimum amount of integers we need to have in the sum (for example, is it required that $n>5$ or something?)

Comment: Would it help if there was a condition such that for an a_i, a_i <= i?

Comment: @SultanofQuizikhstam, why dont you post the actual problem without making us all guess?

Comment: I'm sorry about that, but this problem was one I heard of and needed to look at again, and when I asked it got messed up a little. Again, sorry!

Answer (score 2):

One can accomplish this by choosing the signs $s_n,s_{n-1},\dots,s_2,s_1\in\{-1,1\}$ of $a_n,a_{n-1},\dots,a_2,a_1$, in that order, as follows:

Choose $s_n$ arbitrarily. For each $k\in\{n-1,n-2,\dots,2,1\}$, choose $s_k$ to be the negative of the sign of $s_{k+1}a_{k+1} + \cdots + s_na_n$. (If that sum equals $0$, choose $s_k$ arbitrarily.)

It's simple to show inductively that with this scheme (and under the assumption $1\le a_k\le k$), we have $|s_ka_k + \cdots + s_na_n| \le k$ for each $k\in\{n,n-1,\dots,2,1\}$. In particular, $|s_1a_1 + \cdots + s_na_n| \le 1$.

The above didn't even use the fact that the $a_j$ are integers (only the bounds $1\le a_k\le k$). But if the $a_j$ are integers, then $s_1a_1 + \cdots + s_na_n$ is also an integer that has the same parity as $a_1 + \cdots + a_n$. In particular, if that latter sum is even, then $s_1a_1 + \cdots + s_na_n$ is an even integer that is at most $1$ in absolute value, hence must equal $0$.

Comment: Wow this is very thorough thanks!

Comment: The way to thank someone on this website, Sultan, is to "accept" the answer by clicking in the check mark next to the answer.